# Python 3 guessing game - int() argument error

Tags: python

This is the code in its full extent at the moment:

```
import random
import time

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

mode_chosen = 0
def update_mode():
    global mode_chosen
    mode_chosen = entry.get()
    mode()

def mode():
    if mode_chosen == "1":
        new_player()
    if mode_chosen == "2":
        existing_player()
    if mode_chosen == "3":
        exit()

def new_player():
    global username
    entry_entry.pack_forget()
    entry1_entry.pack()
    choose_button.pack(side="bottom")

    screen_var.set("      Make a username or\ntype exit to leave the game")
    username = entry1.get()
    if username == "exit":
        exit()
    if username != "":
        screen_var.set("""Hello {}, here's how to play my game. I will think of a number between 1 and value depending on the difficulty you will choose, this will also decide how many tries you have to guess my number.""".format(username))  
        game()

def existing_player():
    global username
    entry_entry.pack_forget()
    entry1_entry.pack()
    choose_button.pack(side="bottom")

    screen_var.set("Please enter your username or type exit to leave the game") 
    username = entry1.get()
    if username == "exit":
        exit()
    if username != "":
        screen_var.set("\nWelcome back {}.".format(username))
        game()

def game():
    top = 0
    tries = 0
    screen_var.set("Pick a level of difficulty (e.g 1, 2, 3) or type exit to leave the game")
    entry1_entry.pack_forget()
    entry2_entry.pack()
    level = ""
    level = entry2.get() 

    if level == "1":
        top += 10
        tries = 2
        screen_var.set("\nWell I am thinking of a number between 1 and {}, you have {} tries to guess my number.\nType exit at anytime to leave the game.".format(top, tries + 1))
    elif level == "2":
        top += 20
        tries = 5
        screen_var.set("\nWell I am thinking of a number between 1 and {}, you have {} tries to guess my number.\nType exit at anytime to leave the game.".format(top, tries + 1))
    elif level == "3":
        top += 30
        tries = 8
        screen_var.set("\nWell I am thinking of a number between 1 and {}, you have {} tries to guess my number.\nType exit at anytime to leave the game.".format(top, tries + 1))
elif level == "exit":
    exit()

number = random.randint(1, top)
guesses_taken = 0
entry2_entry.pack_forget()
entry3_entry.pack()
guess = entry3.get
answer = int(guess)

while guesses_taken <= tries:
    screen_var.set("Take a guess: ")
    guesses_taken += 1

    if answer < 1:
        print("Guess a number between 1 and {}.".format(top))
        guess_taken -= 1
    if answer > top:
        print("Guess a number between 1 and {}.".format(top))
        guess_taken -= 1
    if answer < number:
        print("Your guess is too low")
    if answer > number:
        print("Your guess is too high")
    if answer == number:
        break
    if guess == "exit":
        exit()


if answer == number:
    print("Good job, {}! You guessed my number in {} guesses!".format(username, guesses_taken))
if answer != number:
    print("Nope. The number I was thinking of was: {}.".format(number))

def exit():
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("Guessing Game")


label1 = Label(root, text="Guessing Game")
label1.pack()

screen_var = StringVar()
screen_var.set("""Choose a mode by entering the number:
1: New Player
2: Existing Player
3: Exit
""")

screen_label = Label(root, textvariable=screen_var, justify="left")
screen_label.pack()

answer_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Answer: ")
answer_label.pack()

entry = StringVar()
entry_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry)
entry_entry.pack()

entry1 = StringVar()
entry1_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry1)

entry2 = StringVar()
entry2_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry2)

entry3 = StringVar()
entry3_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry3)

choose_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Choose", command=update_mode)
choose_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

At the moment I am running through moving the programme into a python gui, when it comes in this part:

```
answer = int(guess)
```

It gives me the error message of:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\GUI test\Gui_Game.py", line 11, in update_mode
mode()
  File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\GUI test\Gui_Game.py", line 15, in mode
new_player()
  File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\GUI test\Gui_Game.py", line 33, in new_player
game()
  File "C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\GUI test\Gui_Game.py", line 81, in game
answer = int(guess)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'
```

If anyone can help me find a solution to this error, it would be greatly apprieciated. Thanks.

Comment: entry3.get should probably be entry3.get()

Comment: guess = entry3.get()

Comment: `guess = entry3.get` passes a function reference, you don't get the value. `int()` accepts a string, a byte-like object or a number. Do `guess = entry3.get()`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, im relatively new to coding so that should have been an easy thing to pick up. Unfortunately that hasnt fixed the problem. It now comes up with the error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What did you input? @Lewis You'll need a try/except for cases you accidentally input something non-covertable

Comment: in the gui, it asks for the player to input a difficulty level, that being 1, 2 or 3. Any of those numbers bring up the error.

Comment: Oh, you can't convert it into an integer right away when the program starts or else it will try to convert an empty string!

Comment: How would i go about solving that?

Comment: How do you start the game? Does the player click on a button to start the game? Add the `guess` assignment and `int` inside that function

Comment: To start the game the player has to pick a mode, in the code it is the mode_chosen and update_mode functions. If i put answer = int(guess) into either of them is states guess is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so.

On line 77, you have

`guess = entry3.get`

entry3.get is a function. So instead it would be,

`guess = entry3.get()`

Sometimes you can use something like `print(type(entry3.get))` and it'll say

`<class 'method'> <bound method StringVar.get of <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x034A6410>>`

Which tells us it's a function and needs to have `()` after it.

Thanks,

~Coolq